# Как можно передавать данные между html страницами ? java spring mvc thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, mvc, thymeleaf

Расскажите пожалуйста о способах передачи данных между html страницами(при использовании **java**, **spring** **mvc**,**thymeleaf**).
Я делаю проект расписание занятий.Проблема в том, что на одной странице я выбираю **факультет, номер группы** и нажимаю на кнопку. Меня перекидывает на другую вьюху, в которой отображается расписание для **выбранной группы** , можно удалить запись и редактировать. есть кнопка добавить расписание для этой группы,она отправляет на другую страницу для добавления данных.
 Как можно передавать данные между страницами ?
Я знаю только :
1) отправкой формы(тег `<form>`)
 2) чтобы параметр содержался в ссылке
как можно это сделать ещё.
***Буду рад любой помощи)))***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите открывать тот или иной объект для изменения/добавления/удаления, то в ссылке лучше добавлять Id сущности для  удаления. И прибегать к  [`@PathVariable`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-optional-path-variables). Иными словами вы создаете ссылки в формате:

```
/deleteObject/{id} -> /deleteObject/1,  /deleteObject/2,  /deleteObject/3.
```

После с помощью `@PathVariable` ищите объект в БД и удаляете/редактируете его

Как-то так я воспринял ваш вопрос